# UWP Get Page type from User Control from code-behind

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have a user control that is reused on multiple pages, including MainPage. I would like to perform some logic in the user control **if** the event happens on the current page for the instance of the user control. The logic is the same no matter what the page is, so I'd prefer not to have the user control invoke a delegate from the parent page.

```
    //Event method in the user control:
    private void Dummy_Event(object sender, DummyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle global application events only if this page is active
        if (((Frame)Window.Current.Content).CurrentSourcePageType == typeof(/* PAGE TYPE */))
        {
            //DO STUFF
        }
    }
```

In the `if` statement I'm checking if the application's current page type is equal to the page that this instance of the user control is a child of.

I could do repetitive calls of `this.Parent`, but even if I do eventually get to a `Page` element, there's no way of telling which page it is as far as I know.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you just add a boolean property to the usercontrol and set it to true in the xaml of the parent pages that you wish to run this additional logic on?

Comment: Sry, I didn't get what you asked for. You've already get the Page Type by `CurrentSourcePageType`. Then what else do you want?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT the `CurrentSourcePageType` is the current page, but I need to compare it to the page that the instance of the user control belongs to, since all pages are cached and I don't want the code to run if that specific page isn't the active one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things get a bit messy if you make it the responsibility of the `UserControl` itself to figure out if it is inside the current `Page` of a `Frame`. I would follow Mark's suggestion and expose a Boolean property (perhaps `IsActive`) which you can use to decide whether or not you should handle that event within the `UserControl`. It now becomes the responsibility of each `Page` to set this flag inside `OnNavigatedTo` and to clear it inside `OnNavigatedFrom`.